# Validating the string for not starting with number in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to validate the variable name where it should not start with number but can include numbers

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z0-9_]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only Alphanumeric characters and Underscore ('_') is allowed. All letters must be in Upper Case.")]
```

The above expression doesn't restrict the starting string with Number.

Comment: Use: `^[^0-9]\w*$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression for validating a string which is not starting with a number.

```
[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regular expression for validating a string that doesn't start with a number, but can contain a number

```
^[^0-9]\w*$
```

and you can always use this website for testing can modifying your RegEx

> https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is the right answer, It will prompt error if string starts with a number.

```
^(?!^[0-9].*$).*
```

Thanks